# forward selection method using R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to use the forward selection method to fit the best multiple linear regression model based on AIC

```
wins%   #runs scored   batting.avg    #double.p    #walks     #strickouts
0.599   608            0.245          135          425        1079
0.586   682            0.252          124          408        1060
0.556   675            0.265          189          469        882
0.549   825            0.273          142          587        1113
0.531   708            0.256          145          541        996
0.528   654            0.250          153          466        1071
0.497   707            0.254          152          467        916
0.444   635            0.238          166          481        855
0.401   569            0.237          130          388        931
0.309   495            0.221          153          498        776


model.s <- lm(formula = winning.percentage ~ ., data = new.table)

step <- stepAIC(model.s, direction = "forward")
summary(step)
```

Output

```
Start:  AIC=-243.36
winning.percentage ~ number.of.runs.scored + batting.average + 
    total.number.of.double.plays + other.teams.number.of.walks + 
    number.of.strikouts


Call:
lm(formula = winning.percentage ~ number.of.runs.scored + batting.average + 
    total.number.of.double.plays + other.teams.number.of.walks + 
    number.of.strikouts, data = new.table)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.108803 -0.020586  0.007429  0.022087  0.083116 

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  -0.2776752  0.1913151  -1.451  0.15583    
number.of.runs.scored         0.0002778  0.0001466   1.895  0.06659 .  
batting.average               1.7419995  0.9284706   1.876  0.06923 .  
total.number.of.double.plays  0.0007370  0.0004502   1.637  0.11084    
other.teams.number.of.walks  -0.0005897  0.0001292  -4.566 6.23e-05 ***
number.of.strikouts           0.0003461  0.0001044   3.315  0.00219 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04457 on 34 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.646, Adjusted R-squared:  0.594 
F-statistic: 12.41 on 5 and 34 DF,  p-value: 6.856e-07
```

if I run the model with all the predictors I get this output and if I run stepAIC function I get the same output. is this normal?

Comment: Stepwise regression [is a garbage generator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/11849). You are actually lucky that you get the full model.

Comment: Try adding the `trace = TRUE` argument to `stepAIC` to see what it is doing.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I tried that. it did not show the steps.

Comment: It only shows steps it took so in thisw case it did not take any (as opposed to not showing the steps it took).